# Recursive function to print numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function to print 1 to 10 in JavaScript, my current code is:

```
function rec10(x)
 {

       if (x < 10)
       {

       $('#text').val(x+1);
       x = x+1;
       rec10(x);

       }



 }
```

The problem is, everytime I activate this function, the text box only shows "10" directly, i want the code to move from 0 to 1, to 2... until 10. Showing each one of them in the text box.
I tried to use setInterval and setTimeout but I didn't figure it out how to work with that. Thank you very much

Comment: Use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, if you must use recursion you'll have to print to the console.

Comment: Why do you need a recursion?

Comment: setTimeout(function() {  rec10(x); }, 1000); instead of rec10(x);

Comment: Musa, I already tried that, and stills shows only 10 in the text box

Comment: PM 77-1, i'm just trying to improve my skills and learn new things, that's why i'm using recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of:

```
rec10(x);
```

call

```
setTimeout(function() { rec10(x); }, 1000);
```

Comment: That worked pretty well, can you tell me why do i need to do that? calling a timeout instead of the function itself

Comment: @bert, see my answer below.

Comment: @bert: because the function normally goes *so fast* that the browser never really has a 'window' to update the textbox. Visually it goes straight to ten. You need to artificially add this delay to give the browser time to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

With `setInterval` you can using code below:

```
function rec10(x) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (x >= 10) clearInterval(interval);
        $('#text').val(x++);
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded, which means while your code runs, the changes you make to the DOM won't be seen on the browser until your code finish.

You need to give control to the browser for couple of seconds, it can be done with `setTimeout`:

```
function rec10(x){

       if (x < 10){
           $('#text').val(++x);

       setTimeout(function(){
           rec10(x);               
       },20);

       }
 }
```

Comment: 20ms might be a little too short

Comment: @Paul, and why is that?

Comment: 20ms is PLENTY of time for that little JS function . . .

Comment: OP says he wants to see each number show up in the box.  But at 20ms/number, all 10 numbers will flash by in 1/5 of a second.

Comment: @gdoron Thank you for the information, just one more question, I tried using setTimeout(rec10(x), 1000); and didn't work, is it a syntax issue?

Comment: @Paul, he just want to practice his javascript skills, he doesn't really care about actually "reading" the numbers from the textbox. 20ms is a good example of a how you need to give control of a short period of time.

Comment: @bert, you used `setTimeout` wrong. The first parameter should be a pointer to a function, not a function call(which simply runs right away and returns its return value which is in this case undefined).

Comment: @gdoro  I get it... I got problems with that because the first recursive function i did i just used a bool value, so it was a infinite loop while the bool was true, so i just did a setInterval in it and worked pretty well, using setInterval(rec10(), 1000), that's why i did that again with this new function

Comment: @gdoro Why can't I use a setInterval in this case?

Comment: @bert, who said you can't? `setInterval` is a valid option.

Comment: @gdoro How can I do that in this case? just a point, setInterval = executes over and over again the function each period of time and setTimeout = executes one time the function in that period of time. So, the setTimout only worked because the function was recursive(parameter x untill 10), is that it ?

Comment: @bert, If I understood you correctly, yes, you're right.

Comment: @gdoron Thank you very much, how could i do that using a setInterval ? It's the last quetion, i swear :)

Comment: @bert, You got an answer showing it already... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26707203/601179 .BTW, xcera's answer is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see it... But I think the best option right now is the setTimout method, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Did you resort to `setInterval`/`setTimeout` only because you can't make a working recursive function?
If that's the case, how about this recursive function below without using `setInterval`/`setTimeout`:

```
function rec10(x) {
    if (x <= 10) {
        if (x <= 0) x = 1;

        //append?
        $('#text').val(x);

        rec10(x + 1);
    }
}

rec10(1);
```

But the problem with the code above is it will happen so fast you won't notice the printing of numbers `1` up to `9`.
If you want to see the those numbers then I suggest you just append the value to your placeholder  `$('#text')`.
But if you really wanna see the numbers being printed and then being replaced by the next number, then you can refer to the answers posted by other users which uses `setInterval`/`setTimeout`.

Comment: I understand, but I basically wanted to do a "count up", so I had to slow down the function :)

Comment: @bert, this is not true: _"But the problem with the code above is it will happen so fast you won't notice the printing of numbers 1 up to 9."_ It's not because of the speed but because of the single threaded nature of javascript.

Comment: @gdoron, i'm talking about execution time, regardless of single-threaded or not, it will always happen so fast to be observable by human eye. Can you observe the printing of 1-9 without using any form of delays?

Comment: Even you spam actions that takes 1 seconds you won't see changes. Test it.